# Main water line TDS measurement grounding

Tags: grounding, water, conductivity

I am trying to implement a TDS sensor to measure a main water line connected pipe, with circuitry that is powered from the wall.

My TDS circuit is essentially a two electrode conductivity probe with one end having a square wave signal and the other a resistor divider referenced to ground.
When the TDS goes over 1000 ppm NaCl the readings become very different to the battery powered TDS meter I am referencing against. My thought is that as the ppm increases the conductivity of the water also increases, and since the water itself is grounded through the pipes to earth ground that there is an alternate path messing up the measurements.

Has anyone had any experience like this with high TDS inline water measurements? Running on batteries is not an option. I am considering an opto-isolator or transformer but I have not seen anything like this talked about online.

Comment: Just to cover all the bases, you mention it's a square wave, but is it an AC balanced square wave? ie. ±5v or 0-5v?

Comment: +200mV to -200mV balanced 2.4kHz square wave made from a 0 to +3V3 50% duty cycle PWM pin output.

Comment: It sounds like you are assuming that the dissolved solids are ionic; they change the conductivity of the solution. I'm not sure that is a valid assumption. In my experience, TDS sensors use optical methods rather than conductivity.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson As a second opinion, my experience with TDS has all been with conductive sensors. It works quite well.

Comment: @pbandjazz As a quick test can you use a transformer to power your circuit? All my experience with TDS had them in lengths of plastic pipes, some distance, 6ft. or more from any copper pipes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are correct, in that the GND is messing with your measurement.

Here are a few options:

- Isolate the resistance measurement circuit using opto-isolators and an isloated DC-DC converter.
- Compensate for the current leaking to ground by periodically switching off the ground electrode, and measuring the "0" signal. This will give you a resistance to ground which you can remove from your measurement.
- Change the sensor installation so the resistance to the undesired GND is greater (put it in a plastic pipe).
- You can also move the electrodes closer together, so the leakage is a relatively smaller part of the signal. For example if your signal is ~10ohms, and the parasitic path to ground is ~100 ohms, that will cause a 9% change. If the electrodes were 1/10th the distance apart, and the signal was in the range of 1ohm, the parasitic ground would only cause a change of 1%.